# Mounting windows 7 shared drive from my VM in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, mount, network-shares

First my setup:

- I have Ubuntu 10.04 and i am using Oracle VirtualBox to run my Windows 7.

On my windows i have access to a the shared drives for example, all i need to do is go tools-> map drive and i can enter the name of the drive (user/password) and i am done:

```
\\smalldrive
```

so i am trying to access the same drive on ubuntu, because i dont want to open the VM just to access those files.

I have read on [Liberian Geek](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/08/mount-windows-shares-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx-terminal/) How to mount the share on ubuntu, but i am missing some piece of information to make it work:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //Windows_PC/Shares /mnt/Windows -o user=username
                   ^----Here---^
```

how can i get the name of the computer from which i am getting the shared folder.
I was thinking even if i can get the ip address i can use it in place of the name.

So unless someone has a better suggestion here is what i need:

- How can i get the ip address of the computer from the shared drive
- How can i mount it directly on ubuntu.

EDIT:

The shared drive is not on my machine but on a different machine on the network. i don't know the name of the computer nor the ip address

Comment: Make sure your VM is configured to use "Bridged networking" - otherwise the guest system will not be accessible from others computers than the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching for a long time, I realized it was something very easy to do.

In Windows 7, in the command line I did a ping:

```
ping smalldrive
```

This returned the IP address of the server hosting this drive.

In my Ubuntu machine I simply used a regular mount:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //New IP/Shares /mnt/Windows -o user=username
```

and now I don't have to run my Windows VM just to access this shared folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IP address to mount to the Windows share. On the Windows box, go to a command prompt and type:

```
ipconfig[ENTER]
```

This should give you the IP address of the network adapter on the Windows machine.

Then on the Linux machine you can mount the share with:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //10.0.0.2/Shares /mnt/Windows -o user=username
```

Where 10.0.0.2 is the IP address of the Windows virtual machine.

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. I added a little edit, to mention that the network drive i am accessing is not on my machine, but on a different computer on the network.

Comment: You can get the info from your Windows 7 machine. View the properties of the network share shortcut, and it should tell you the server name or ip address.

Comment: @Joe i tried right clicking, and go on property, i went through all the tabs, and i cant see that information

Comment: Sorry about that... you can look in the "Network Neighborhood" to see what other servers show up, run `net view` from the command line and see if it lists a SMB/SAMBA server, or if you have registry access (run regedt32), look under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\<drive-letter>`. It will be listed as `RemotePath`.